# Importrange from multiple google spread sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I know how to import data from ONE spread sheet to another:

```
=IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_key, range_string)
```

Source: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en&ref_topic=3105411

But how do I import MULTIPLE spread sheets into one "master spread sheet"?

Something like this:

```
=IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_key, range_string),IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_key, range_string),IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_key, range_string)
```

All spread sheets have the exact same structure.

I want all data in the same sheet in the same columns.

Preferebly I would like to import all spread sheets automaticly that are placed in one folder into the "master spread sheat".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Formula

You can concatenate values and ranges.
In the English locale you concatenate columns with `,` and rows with `;` annd putting them in curlies `{` and `}`.

Try the following:

```
={IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_key1, range_string1);
  IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_key2, range_string2);
  IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_key3, range_string3)}
```

### Function

A rough method to automatically import all sheets in a folder.

```
function import() {
  var spreadsheets = DriveApp.
    getFolderById("YOURFOLDERID").
    getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);

  var data = [];
  while (spreadsheets.hasNext()) {
    var currentSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheets.next().getId());
    data = data.concat(currentSpreadsheet.   
                         getSheetByName("YOURSTANDARDSHEETNAME").
                         getRange("YOURSTANDARDDATARANGE").
                         getValues());
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.
    getActiveSheet().
    getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).
    setValues(data);
}
```

This doesn't handle ranges that get smaller and thus not overwrite the old data or anything fancy.
It also still needs to be manually triggered.

Comment: Thanks! I don't get the formula to work. What is "YOURSTANDARDSHEETNAME"? Can YOURSTANDARDDATARANGE some how be the complete document no matter how many rows and columns there are?

Comment: If the `IMPORTRANGE` range is always `"Sheet1!A1:F10"` then `"YOURSTANDARDSHEETNAME"` is always `"Sheet1"`and `"YOURSTANDARDRANGE"` is always `"A1:F10"`. the complete sheet would need `getDataRange()` instead of `getRange()`.

Comment: Formula worked fine. Function didn't work for me with getDataRange but worked with getRange. Though I didn't have the permisson to read the data from the folder. only worked in script mode. but thanks!

Comment: Is it your folder? Did  you enter the right foler ID?

Comment: Yes and yes. Yes, but it says that I don't have permission to read that folder. Running it from script mode loads the data in the file though. But "=import" in column A1 gets replaced by the data when doing so. I use Google Apps.

Comment: if you want to use `import()` as a spreadsheet function you can just have it `return data;` instead of the `setValues` command. Still not quite sure what the problem with the folder is. Does it work when entering `import()` or does it work when running import from the script editor?