# ImportRange at the bottom of an already present range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to get a sheet to autoupdate with info from a new sheet every day in order to form a weekly aggregate of data. The new sheet will be dropped in the same folder and will be given the same name every day. Currently the process works, when I drop a new sheet into the folder it gets the Key Id and imports the new unique data from said sheet.

I'm almost done and my last problem is to make it so that the code doesn't overwrite the data from the previous day. I need to make it so that the code reads the sheet, sees the active range (how many rows there are) and then places the importrange function in the cell directly below the last entry on the sheet (ie if the previous day's data ends on row 166, the import range function for today goes on A:167).

What is the best way to accomplish this range function each day? I know that executing it will probably be as simple as adding +1 to a variable for the importrange, but how can I accomplish this range reading function? Will getRange do the trick or is there something more specific having to do with row number?

Here's the code:

```
//trigger from user action upload new sheet
// get sheet key from new sheet
//specify new cell in monthly for import range
// put new key in import range function in sheet
//execute import range
//var counter = 0;



//var import= "IMPORTRANGE""(""1K7Rj4QK-EVjf8lZ0BSew7iDeCtktqWjzgjoaVPe5jSc""," "sheet1!A1:G6"")"

var counter = 0;

function test() {
  var files = [];
  var keyID = [];

function searchFolder() {
 var folderId = '0B6wmHZ5c0fzfTjI1bFpKOHI3N3M'; // test folder
  // Log the name of every file in the folder.
  var filesN = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles(); //log files in folder
  while (filesN.hasNext()) {
    var file = filesN.next();
    keyID.push(file.getId())
    files.push(file.getName());
  }
  Logger.log(keyID)

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1lH9Y12P2Q2OFndIJoAU48ePggXFc9WGcWjolZMcABoc");     //defines target spreadsheet ie monthly
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss); //sets target spreadsheet as active
    var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    for (var i = 0; i < keyID.length; i++) { 
      var range = s.getRange(1,i+1); //sets range in target. ONLY CHOOSE ONE
      range.setValue('=IMPORTRANGE("'+keyID[i]+'","sheet1!A1:167")')
    }
  autoUpdate(keyID);
}

function autoUpdate(){ //updates monthly from newly imported daily
  if (counter == 1){ //counter is made to be 1 when day is uploaded to monthly
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1lH9Y12P2Q2OFndIJoAU48ePggXFc9WGcWjolZMcABoc"); //defines target spreadsheet ie monthly
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss); //sets target spreadsheet as active
 var range= ss.getRange("A1:A1"); //sets range in target. ONLY CHOOSE ONE CELL FOR IMPORTRANGE- IF MORE THAN 1 IS CHOSEN YOU WILL GET A #REF ERROR BECAUSE IT WILL PUT IMPORTRANGE IN ALL CELLS
 range.activate;  // activates range
 //range.setValue('=IMPORTRANGE("1hVv6ldHEaCCI_uptr0MpzAyP60x7on8YR_brWwWXTWo","sheet1!A1:167")');
  range.setValue(('=IMPORTRANGE("'+keyID+'","sheet1!A1:167")'));//Puts in IMPORTRANGE into target as a STRING value (just words). Once it hits the sheet, then SHEETS executes IMPORTRANGE not SCRIPTS. In Source sheet, range is selected to import to target (ie A1:G6)
 counter=(counter-1)
  }
 }

function timeStamp(){
  if (files == "Daily") {
  counter= (counter+1)
  }
}

searchFolder();
timeStamp();
autoUpdate();

}
```

Comment: consider you can concatenate multiple imporrange with a single formula. You may use that to solve your case. http://stackoverflow.com/q/38924637/2213940

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's only ever one file in the folder at a time you don't need to loop through the keyID array... you can simply get the first (and only element) by keyID[0]...to get the next row for the import range you can use `s.getLastRow()`.  See [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) for documentation.  Your full code would change to the following.  Notice the alteration where the second loop was.

```
//trigger from user action upload new sheet
// get sheet key from new sheet
//specify new cell in monthly for import range
// put new key in import range function in sheet
//execute import range
//var counter = 0;



//var import= "IMPORTRANGE""(""1K7Rj4QK-EVjf8lZ0BSew7iDeCtktqWjzgjoaVPe5jSc""," "sheet1!A1:G6"")"

var counter = 0;

function test() {
  var files = [];
  var keyID = [];

  function searchFolder() {
    var folderId = '0B6wmHZ5c0fzfTjI1bFpKOHI3N3M'; // test folder
    // Log the name of every file in the folder.
    var filesN = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles(); //log files in folder
    while (filesN.hasNext()) {
      var file = filesN.next();
      keyID.push(file.getId())
      files.push(file.getName());
    }
    Logger.log(keyID)

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1lH9Y12P2Q2OFndIJoAU48ePggXFc9WGcWjolZMcABoc");     //defines target spreadsheet ie monthly
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss); //sets target spreadsheet as active
    var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    s.getRange(s.getLastRow()+1,1).setValue('=IMPORTRANGE("'+keyID[0]+'","sheet1!A1:167")')

    autoUpdate(keyID);
  }

  function autoUpdate(){ //updates monthly from newly imported daily
    if (counter == 1){ //counter is made to be 1 when day is uploaded to monthly
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1lH9Y12P2Q2OFndIJoAU48ePggXFc9WGcWjolZMcABoc"); //defines target spreadsheet ie monthly
      SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss); //sets target spreadsheet as active
      var range= ss.getRange("A1:A1"); //sets range in target. ONLY CHOOSE ONE CELL FOR IMPORTRANGE- IF MORE THAN 1 IS CHOSEN YOU WILL GET A #REF ERROR BECAUSE IT WILL PUT IMPORTRANGE IN ALL CELLS
      range.activate;  // activates range
      //range.setValue('=IMPORTRANGE("1hVv6ldHEaCCI_uptr0MpzAyP60x7on8YR_brWwWXTWo","sheet1!A1:167")');
      range.setValue(('=IMPORTRANGE("'+keyID+'","sheet1!A1:167")'));//Puts in IMPORTRANGE into target as a STRING value (just words). Once it hits the sheet, then SHEETS executes IMPORTRANGE not SCRIPTS. In Source sheet, range is selected to import to target (ie A1:G6)
      counter=(counter-1)
    }
  }

  function timeStamp(){
    if (files == "Daily") {
      counter= (counter+1)
    }
  }

  searchFolder();
  timeStamp();
  autoUpdate();

}
```